# how to get particular lines in a string

Tags: javascript

**CODE IMPROVEMENT NEEDED**

I have a string containing a text, i want to get a **3 particular lines** in my text, here's the exemple:

```
Text='## THIS IS JUST A TEST \nHELP.\nJust replace `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae. Sed eleifend rhoncus lectus a rutrum.\n Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\n Nullam faucibus lobortis ligula, a iaculis metus feugiat quis. Cras eu luctus purus. Donec hendrerit, ipsum maximus accumsan blandit, est dui eleifend tortor, eget cursus mauris purus in risus.\n Duis fringilla mi nec dolor efficitur, vitae hendrerit nisi tristique.\n@this\n-  USERNAME: userIWANTOGET\n- EMAIL: user@mail.com\n- PASSWORD: USERLISA12.\nNotes:\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae.'


modified_text=Text.split('\n')

firstlineIWantToGet=(modified_text[7])
secondelineIWantToGet=(modified_text[8])
thirdlineIWantToGet=(modified_text[9])

console.log(firstlineIWantToGet)
console.log(secondelineIWantToGet)
console.log(thirdlineIWantToGet)
```

Here's a link to the working code https://repl.it/repls/MisguidedBewitchedBusinesses

I want to get inside a text the value of the Username , Email, password in a better way that i did it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use splice, then you would only have to supply the index:

```js
const text = '## THIS IS JUST A TEST \nHELP.\nJust replace `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae. Sed eleifend rhoncus lectus a rutrum.\n Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\n Nullam faucibus lobortis ligula, a iaculis metus feugiat quis. Cras eu luctus purus. Donec hendrerit, ipsum maximus accumsan blandit, est dui eleifend tortor, eget cursus mauris purus in risus.\n Duis fringilla mi nec dolor efficitur, vitae hendrerit nisi tristique.\n@this\n-  USERNAME: userIWANTOGET\n- EMAIL: user@mail.com\n- PASSWORD: USERLISA12.\nNotes:\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae.'

const index = 7
const details = text.split('\n').splice(index, 3)

console.log(details)
```

Splice will modify the original array, but you said you only wanted the 3 lines, so that should not matter.

I noticed in your repl.it you were using `filter`. I would recommend using `find`, which returns the first result, meaning you don't have to call `toString`. A better way to get this info would be as follows:

```js
const text = '## THIS IS JUST A TEST \nHELP.\nJust replace `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae. Sed eleifend rhoncus lectus a rutrum.\n Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\n Nullam faucibus lobortis ligula, a iaculis metus feugiat quis. Cras eu luctus purus. Donec hendrerit, ipsum maximus accumsan blandit, est dui eleifend tortor, eget cursus mauris purus in risus.\n Duis fringilla mi nec dolor efficitur, vitae hendrerit nisi tristique.\n@this\n-  USERNAME: userIWANTOGET\n- EMAIL: user@mail.com\n- PASSWORD: USERLISA12.\nNotes:\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae.'

const lines = text.split('\n')
const details = ['USERNAME', 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD'].map(input => lines.find(line => line.includes(input)).split(':')[1].trim())

console.log(details)
```

You could even use a regexp to grab the content, so you don't even have to split the text:

```js
const text = '## THIS IS JUST A TEST \nHELP.\nJust replace `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae. Sed eleifend rhoncus lectus a rutrum.\n Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\n Nullam faucibus lobortis ligula, a iaculis metus feugiat quis. Cras eu luctus purus. Donec hendrerit, ipsum maximus accumsan blandit, est dui eleifend tortor, eget cursus mauris purus in risus.\n Duis fringilla mi nec dolor efficitur, vitae hendrerit nisi tristique.\n@this\n-  USERNAME: userIWANTOGET\n- EMAIL: user@mail.com\n- PASSWORD: USERLISA12.\nNotes:\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae.'

const details = ['USERNAME', 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD'].map(input => text.match(new RegExp(`${input}: (.*)`))[1])

console.log(details)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but **I would match text using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)**. Perhaps something like the following:

```
text.match(
  /USERNAME: *?.*$|EMAIL: *?.*$|PASSWORD: *?.*$/gm
)
```

This gets you each of the key/value pairs that may or may not have been included in the text:

```
[
  'USERNAME: userIWANTOGET',
  'EMAIL: user@mail.com',
  'PASSWORD: USERLISA12.',
]
```

After that, you can just split the key/value pair apart on the `:` separator and, optionally, create an object from them:

```
{
  EMAIL: 'user@mail.com',
  PASSWORD: 'USERLISA12.',
  USERNAME: 'userIWANTOGET',
}
```

In the snippet below, I used [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create this object, which may need some additional code in Edge (and IE) to work right. I also used [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an object containing default values for the expected keys - I find this makes the object more predictable when these values aren't found.

```js
const text =
`## THIS IS JUST A TEST
HELP.
Just replace \`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae. Sed eleifend rhoncus lectus a rutrum.
 Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
 Nullam faucibus lobortis ligula, a iaculis metus feugiat quis. Cras eu luctus purus. Donec hendrerit, ipsum maximus accumsan blandit, est dui eleifend tortor, eget cursus mauris purus in risus.
 Duis fringilla mi nec dolor efficitur, vitae hendrerit nisi tristique.
 @this
 -  USERNAME: userIWANTOGET
 - EMAIL: user@mail.com
 - PASSWORD: USERLISA12.
 Notes:
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam egestas eros non pharetra maximus. Suspendisse congue augue in dui sollicitudin tincidunt. Praesent blandit lorem eros, nec aliquet lacus sagittis vitae.`

// Get USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD
const matches = text.match(
  /USERNAME: *?.*$|EMAIL: *?.*$|PASSWORD: *?.*$/gm
)

// NOTE: Object.fromEntries() may need a polyfill for Edge/IE
const valuesFromText = Object.fromEntries(
  matches.map(str => str.split(/: */))
)

const defaultValues = {
  USERNAME: '',
  EMAIL: '',
  PASSWORD: '',
}

const values = Object.assign({}, defaultValues, valuesFromText)

console.log(values)
```